# Redirect PHP to success/error page

Tags: php, forms, email, redirect

I've found a few examples on this site and I mixed them. The code works (goes to success page), but how can I test if it would work to go to error page?

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $NOMBRE = $_POST['NOMBRE'];
    $APELLIDO = $_POST['APELLIDO'];
    $TELEFONO = $_POST['TELEFONO'];
    $DIRECCION_DE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO = $_POST['DIRECCION_DE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO'];
    $TIPO_DE_EVENTO = $_POST['TIPO_DE_EVENTO'];
    $FECHA_DEL_EVENTO = $_POST['FECHA_DEL_EVENTO'];
    $CONSULTA = $_POST['CONSULTA'];
    $NOMBRE_DEL_ESPACIO = $_POST['NOMBRE_DEL_ESPACIO'];
    $DIRECCION = $_POST['DIRECCION'];
    $CANTIDAD_DE_INVITADOS = $_POST['CANTIDAD_DE_INVITADOS'];
    $SERVICIOS_CONTRATADOS = $_POST['SERVICIOS_CONTRATADOS'];
    $CUALES = $_POST['CUALES'];
    $COMO_LLEGO_A_ESTE_SITIO = $_POST['COMO_LLEGO_A_ESTE_SITIO'];
    $formcontent=" De: $NOMBRE $APELLIDO \n Telefono: $TELEFONO / E-mail: $DIRECCION_DE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO \n \n Tipo de evento: $TIPO_DE_EVENTO / Fecha del eveno: $FECHA_DEL_EVENTO \n \n Mensaje: \n $CONSULTA \n Espacio: '$NOMBRE_DEL_ESPACIO' ($DIRECCION) \n Cantidad de invitados: $CANTIDAD_DE_INVITADOS \n $SERVICIOS_CONTRATADOS cuento con servicios contratados \n $CUALES \n ¿Como llego a este sitio? $COMO_LLEGO_A_ESTE_SITIO";
    $recipient = "gdmtgdmt@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Mensaje desde sitio web";
    $mailheader = "De: $DIRECCION_DE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO \r\n";

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
        header("Location: e-consultasenviado.htm");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: e-consultasnoenviado.htm");
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deliberately want to cause an error in order to check if the error page is loaded, then just put a **`!`** in your check to produce **`false`**. (*Be sure to remove it afterwards as it won't send the email*).

```
if (!mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    header("Location: e-consultasenviado.htm");
}
else {
    header("Location: e-consultasnoenviado.htm");
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help @gdmt :)